# How to force tsc to ignore node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I'm using tsc build tasks. Unfortunately I'm always getting the same errors from the node modules folder

```
Executing task: .\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd --watch -p .\tsconfig.json <
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(6208,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(6215,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(6219,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(6225,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(6226,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakSet'.
10:13:18 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

I already added the directory to the ignore at `tsconfig.json`

```json
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
      },
      "include": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "./node_modules",
        "./node_modules/*",
        "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
      ]
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? What should I do in order to ignore those errors?

I'm using VSCode and tsc Version 2.9.2

Comment: This could be helpful: **"...To do so, the compiler needs the definition of a module, this could be a .ts file for your own code, or a .d.ts for an imported definition file. If the file was found, it will be included regardless of whether it was excluded in the previous steps or not."** -> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-file-in-the-exclude-list-still-picked-up-by-the-compiler

Comment: I want types. I don't want to have to build my project. To do that, I'm using JSDoc, since it uses comments that runners will ignore. The only CLI I could find that could lint my types against the JSDoc is the Typescript CLI with "noEmit": true and "checkJs": true. But then I'm getting errrors from node_modules/utils/utils.js. I don't want theese errors. How can I remove them?

Comment: [Restarting the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273153/this-module-is-declared-with-using-export-and-can-only-be-used-with-a-defau/62275620#62275620) or already `F1 → TypeScript: Reload Project` in VSCode helped to make some Reported Problems disappear

Answer (score 473):

Quickfix is to skip the check

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```

Comment: This worked since the library I was importing was exporting just the types of its own and I was importing the actual files by using script imports so that i can serve them from cdn. Thanks :)

Comment: Docs for this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Works for me with v3.9.7

Comment: This will also skip your type checking of all declaration `*.d.ts` https://dd.engineering/blog/typescript-the-skiplibcheck-option-explained

Comment: does skipLibCheck only target the node_modules folder ?

Comment: @DilipAgheda no it will also target any `d.ts` files outside of `node_modules`. So it is probably not what most people want.

Comment: Note that `tsc --listFiles` seems to ignore this argument, it will still display node_modules typings  (TS 4.2).

Comment: @GianfrancoP.Apparently it will **not** completely disable .d.ts files. Any types your code reaches directly will still be included from those files. Only .d.ts files as a whole won't be checked any more. -- https://dd.engineering/blog/typescript-the-skiplibcheck-option-explained

Comment: Didn't work for version 3.3.x but worked after i upgraded to v4.5

Comment: This doesn't work if you have `checkJs` enabled and a node module contains js files.

Comment: This absolutely does NOT work. I've been banging my head against this for weeks. If you include a module, it gets checked, and there appears to be no way to stop this from happening.

Comment: Explanation of what `skitLibCheck` does: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck

Comment: [Better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277766/4410590) that only ignores `node_modules`: set `types=[]`.

Comment: this has no effect.

Answer (score 74):

Add an empty "types" option in "compilerOptions":

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots

> @types, typeRoots and types
>
> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
> compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
> are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
> ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
> ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
>
> ...
>
> **Specify "types": [] to disable automatic inclusion of @types packages.**
>
> Keep in mind that automatic inclusion is only important if you’re
> using files with global declarations (as opposed to files declared as
> modules). If you use an import "foo" statement, for instance,
> TypeScript may still look through node_modules & node_modules/@types
> folders to find the foo package

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: sorry, I don't understand your point. I just added one line to the tsconfig.json of the OP

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky this addition would probably make your compile run faster. More lines does not automatically make compile time slower. Less lines does not make your code run faster. The caveat here is that this would prevent many projects from compiling without other significant changes due to no longer including types they need.

Comment: Specifying an empty list for CLI worked for me like this `tsc ./myfile.ts --types --someOtherOption`

Comment: This generated even more errors

Answer (score 70):

You can do this right on the command line

```sh
tsc --skipLibCheck
```

Comment: this is better because at least the library types are validated during the webpack build if you're using webpack plugins to validate the included library types

Comment: This worked for me (TS 4.4.4). Even though I had also had it specified in the tsconfig, apparently I explicitly needed to do it like your solution..

Comment: EDIT: Regarding my comment above;

I didn't RTFM, I specified a file in my `tsc` command, which, as is clearly stated in the docs, will ignore the tsconfig; https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#using-tsconfigjson-or-jsconfigjson

Answer (score 47):

I met this issue with `typescript@3.2.1` and fixed by upgrading it to `3.7.3`.

Notice with `typescript@3.2.1`, the `skipLibCheck` does not take effect. When I upgraded TypeScript the `skipLibCheck: true` works.

Comment: was helpful,  upgraded to latest. 3.9.7 and added skipLibCheck

Comment: cool update ts version

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue in a monorepo using yarn workspaces.

Turned out my app was using a different TypeScript version to the root workspace and bringing those in sync fixed the issue.

You can verify this in your own repo by running `yarn list typescript` or `npm ls typescript`.

If you have multiple versions of TypeScript then upgrade your projects with the lower version so that all have the highest version currently in use in your repo, e.g. `yarn add -D typescript@4.5.5` (or whatever version you need)

Comment: Yes. Nothing else seemed to work for me, but this one did. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me, I had different version on my global and my local

Comment: Same issue but with npm workspaces. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

if you are here and none of the following has worked for you:

- ❌ **Updgrade/downgrading typescript version**
  (NOTE: When you run the tsc command, the globally installed typescript version is used as the compiler. So even if you have the latest typescript version in your package.json, **you will have to upgrade typescript globally**. With npm thats `npm install typescript@latest -g` )
- ❌ **Adding/Editing tsconfig options:** *target, types, include, exclude, allowJs, skipLibCheck*
- ❌ **npm update**
- ❌ **Deleting node_modules && npm i**
- ❌ **Deleting package-lock ([don't do that btw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124033/deleting-package-lock-json-to-resolve-conflicts-quickly)) && npm i**

I want to leave this link from the typescript config docs here for you:
[What does this("types") affect?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#what-does-this-affect)

With this knowledge, **this solved the issue for me**:

1. See what module is causing the error in the log when you run `tsc`. (For me it was `node_modules/mongoose/types/*`, so mongoose was the culprit.)
2. Convert all your ES6 imports of this module to commonjs's require(). (In my case `import mongoose from 'mongoose'` --> `const mongoose = require('mongoose')` )

I hope this solves your issue

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your typescript & ts-node:
"typescript": "4.9.4"
"ts-node": "10.9.1"

and use the flag --skipLibCheck when you build or put it in the compilerOtions on the tsconfig.json file ("skipLibCheck": true)...

Answer (score 5):

Happened for me b/c I accidentally imported something from a library with was not part of the public API.
E.g. the `import { ValidationErrorCode } from '@apollo/server/src/plugin/schemaReporting/generated/operations';` caused `tsc` to report type errors in `@apollo/server`. Importing from `src/` or `dist/` should always be a red flag.

Comment: This was my issue, I was importing types not otherwise output by `react-map-gl` and forgot about it, causing this issue. Thanks for being spot on for me, was pulling my hair on this one.

Answer (score 5):

Why not specify the types root, this way the parent "../node_module", "../../node_modules:" etc. will be ignored and only local types will be taken.

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
```

PS This was not working for me in my case only the above approach.

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself here and none of the other answers is solving the problem, check to make sure that you haven't set `maxNodeModuleJsDepth`.
If you have `allowJs` enabled this option lets TypeScript attempt to infer types from modules in `node_modules`, and `skipLibCheck` doesn't have any effect on that, because it's reading javascript files and not type declarations.
The default setting for `maxNodeModuleJsDepth` is `0`, and in the vast majority of cases that's what you want (and you should prefer using `@types` packages instead of turning this on).

Answer (score 3):

This is random but none of the solutions here worked. I had an [error](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/pull/1777) occuring in a node_module and what fixed it was this:

Changing:
`target: "esnext"`

To any specific version, e.g.:
`target: "es2020"`

In case it helps some other poor traveller ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions here worked for me. I only had to upgrade TypeScript from v4 to v5

```
npm install -D typescript@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how you would do so in a bun project!

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["bun-types"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "declaration": false,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "reminder"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 3rd party library is giving you .ts files directly (no d.ts. and not .js), the best way to do it is to use a script to add `// @ts-nocheck` to each file in node_modules.

I use the following for a CI environment setup.

(subsitute npm equivalent for these yarn commands)

```
% yarn 
% find node_modules -type f -name '*.ts' -exec sh -c 'echo "// @ts-nocheck" > /tmp/file.tmp && cat "$1" >> /tmp/file.tmp && mv /tmp/file.tmp "$1"' _ {} \;
% yarn tsc
```

**This here is the magic:**
`find node_modules/@rally -type f -name '*.ts' -exec sh -c 'echo "// @ts-nocheck" > /tmp/file.tmp && cat "$1" >> /tmp/file.tmp && mv /tmp/file.tmp "$1"' _ {} \;`

This will go into the node_modules and find each typescript file (file that ends in .ts) and insert a `// @ts-nocheck` to the top of each file, recursively.

After running the above command, tsc will still run for everything outside node_modules, but will not check the node_modules files.