# TypeScript and React Native, hundreds of errors from node_modules/@types when compiling

Tags: typescript

I am currently migrating my RN project to TypeScript. I have finished the majority of my JS code, and now when I run `tsc` I get several hundred errors that all seem to be

```
error TS 2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property
  prop must be of the type TYPE,
  but here has type TYPE
```

for example:

```
error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property
  'view' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>',
  but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>'.
```

which is doubly confusing because the listed types are almost always identical.

I am able to run my app, I am still getting useful messages from tslint, and any errors specific to my code appear at the bottom of the list of compiler errors.

My `tsconfig.json` is currently:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "es7", "dom", "es6"],
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": ["react-native"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I've tried various solutions, including setting `types` to `[]` as per the TypeScript docs and setting `exclude` to various forms of `node_modules` such as `./node_modules`, `node_modules/*` etc but none of these changes have had any effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I was able to solve this. I'm not totally sure how dependencies are managed via `yarn` but my problem was definitely dependencies.

First I removed all my `@types/*` libraries from my dependencies, and then I deleted my node modules folder.

Then, despite what the majority of tutorials and guides will say, I installed only `@types/react-native` and not `@types/react`. `@types/react-native` added the react typings on its own. I'm thinking that the typings for `@types/react` maybe depended on the node typings, and by explicitly installing them I introduced a bunch of conflicts both between `@types/react-native` and `@types/node` as well as between `@types/react-native` and `@types/react`. My project compiles without error now.

Answer (score 5):

The root cause of the problem appears to be from the Typescript compiler checking the libraries. Adding `skipLibCheck: true` to `tsconfig.json` skips checking the libs.

See [How to force tsc to ignore node_modules folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634361/how-to-force-tsc-to-ignore-node-modules-folder) for detailed explanation.

Comment: this doesn't fix the problem, it just ignores it. you may lose typechecking on library calls like this.