# Trying to tell TypeScript to ignore node_modules, but it's not working. Can you help me out?

Tags: typescript

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/.prisma/*",
    "node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

I'm compiling with `tsx` command, and it still prints out a lot of errors from files in `node_modules` directory:

```
[...]
node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:3907:3 - error TS1135: Argument expression expected.

3907   export class Prisma__TopicClient<T> implements PrismaPromise<T> {
       ~~~~~~

node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:5660:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

5660 }
     ~


Found 136 errors.
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653497/2050306)

Comment: I already have skipLibCheck set to true (see my config above).