# Typescript compiling unused packages

Tags: typescript

Starting with a basic create-react-app, `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`, running `tsc --listFiles` will list some files.
Then installing `npm install @types/lodash-es` for example, and then running `tsc --listFiles` will list every single type for lodash-es as well, even if theres not a single import for it.

Is there anything to prevent that? It seems to increase the compile time as well. For some larger projects, tsc basically just doesn't work for me anymore, just hanging.

Comment: does it help you? [how to force tsc to ignore node modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634361/how-to-force-tsc-to-ignore-node-modules-folder)

Comment: `@types` are automatically included by default.

Comment: It looks like adding "types":[] does remove those files and reduces compile time, but for my larger projects, which have stuff like mui, tsc never finishes and crashes after an extremely long time. Is there any way to exclude everything from node_modules, or at least tell me if something is happening, its just hanging on tsc.