# Getting error on ng serve: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | Dayjs'

Tags: angular, typescript, dayjs

I am working on an Angular Project. I am trying to use [ngx-daterangepicker-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material). I have installed the below packages:

> npm install ngx-daterangepicker-material --save
>
> npm install dayjs --save

I have added sample code shown as per [ngx-daterangepicker-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material).

My component.ts and component.html has below code:

```js
ranges: any = {
    'Today': [dayjs(), dayjs()],
    'Yesterday': [dayjs().subtract(1, 'days'), dayjs().subtract(1, 'days')],
    'Last 7 Days': [dayjs().subtract(6, 'days'), dayjs()],
    'Last 30 Days': [dayjs().subtract(29, 'days'), dayjs()],
    'This Month': [dayjs().startOf('month'), dayjs().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [dayjs().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), dayjs().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
  }

  model: any;
```

```html
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd startKey="start" endKey="end" [ranges]="ranges" [(ngModel)]="model">
```

As soon as I run *ng serve*, I got below error:

```
Error: node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.component.d.ts:173:9 - error TS2380: The return type of a 'get' accessor must be assignable to its 'set' accessor type
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | Dayjs'.

173     get minDate(): dayjs.Dayjs | null;
            ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.component.d.ts:179:9 - error TS2380: The return type of a 'get' accessor must be assignable to its 'set' accessor type

179     get maxDate(): dayjs.Dayjs | null;
            ~~~~~~~
```

As per above error, it does not seem from my code. It is pointing to code under node_modules folder.

Below are the versions from package.json

> "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
>
> "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^6.0.2",

Could someone help in resolving this error?

Comment: could you try [`"skipLibCheck": true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634361/how-to-force-tsc-to-ignore-node-modules-folder)

Comment: maybe you're importing the wrong `dayjs` function. Check which folder it's it imported from. It probably should be the root folder and you're just importing something internal (???) just throwing out ideas

Comment: @NarenMurali thank you for quick response. Adding that the flag of `"skipLibCheck": true` under tsconfig.json resolved that error. Thank you

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli My import statement is `import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';`. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @NarenMurali this `"skipLibCheck": true` seems a temporary relief. Now my page is giving other error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[LocaleService -> LocaleService -> LocaleService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for LocaleService!` I need to check if this is because of that null been allowed as value.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment of  `No provider for LocaleService!`.

**You should configure the necessary providers like below.**

```
    import { LocaleService } from './locale.service';
.
.
.
.


    { provide: LocaleService, useClass: LocaleService, deps: [LOCALE_CONFIG] },
```

For more info, please click [**Here**](https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material/blob/d2c82dc8ed01bf7e1f9442d28e3f9cbb5f532ed9/src/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.module.ts#L23)

Comment: Do I need `LocaleService` for using `Dayjs` or `ngx-daterangepicker-material`? I will try adding LocaleService.

Comment: I hope `ngx-daterangepicker-material`

Comment: as per the code link you provided, `ngx-daterangepicker-material` already adds `LocaleService` in `NgxDaterangepickerMd` module. In my code, I have included `NgxDaterangepickerMd.forRoot()` that means `LocaleService` is available automatically, right. Am I missing anything here.

Comment: I have multiple modules in my project. I had this `NgxDaterangepickerMd.forRoot()` on the module where I have date range component. It was giving `NullInjectorError`. I have also added `NgxDaterangepickerMd.forRoot()` on `AppModule`, then this `NullInjectorError` been gone.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @NarenMurali under comments, adding `"skipLibCheck": true` under `compilerOptions` of *tsconfig.json* file resolved this issue.

PS: I had faced another issue of getting `NullInjectorError`. It was because of my module hierarchy. After adding `NgxDaterangepickerMd.forRoot()` under `AppModule`, that error been resolved.