# How do i exclude node_modules folder from TSC?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I know this question had been asked many times before, however no solution so far had worked for me.

This is what i have included in my `tsconfig` file:

```
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
...
"exclude": ["node_modules/*"]
```

Yet i still get TS errors for files in my `node_modules` folder.
Adding `"explainFiles": true` to the config also verifies those files are included.

What am i missing?

Full config:

```
{
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, // Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file
  "noImplicitReturns": true, // Report error when not all code paths in function return a value
  "noUnusedLocals": true, // Report errors on unused locals
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "explainFiles": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2020"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
    },
    "types": ["jest", "chrome"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "test"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Can you please try using `{
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
` once and check?

Comment: @mandy8055 thanks but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide your full package.json and tsconfig.json so that we can deep dive into the issue?

Based on what you provided and what worked for me (from my experience), you could:

1. Clear typescript compiler cache and rebuild your project - you may want to clear your node_modules/.cache (simply delete it) and your dist (or out) folders and recompile ts again
2. Closely examine your tsconfig.json for any bugs
3. It's simple but make sure your tsconfig.json is in the root directory and is correctly referenced

Also I found this on the web so you may want to try
4. If you have "noImplicitAny": true in your tsconfig.json, consider setting it to false temporarily to see if that resolves the issue

That's all that comes to me just by looking at what you provided.

Comment: None of these unfortunately worked. I added my full config.

Comment: Hmm, i don't see any issue with your config. I found [similar problem to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634361/how-to-force-tsc-to-ignore-node-modules-folder), maybe it will help.